# How can I use pe.entry_point to write YARA rules?

Tags: portable-executable, malware-detection, yara

I wrote condition in YARA rule like this `pe.entry_point == {12 A5 26}` but I am getting unexpected `_HEX_STRING_ error`. What is the problem? How can I get address of `entry_point`? What is the type of output of `pe.entry_point`?

Answer (score 1):

`pe.entry_point` is a `DWORD` found in [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx).

The implementation of this function (that is, how Yara retrieves the `pe.entry_point` value from portable executable files) is available on the Yara [Github page](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara/blob/6d5c1e682b66d5fca443adb3c219bc3dd90fcf7b/libyara/modules/pe.c).

Regarding the error you encountered, try changing the rule to `pe.entry_point == 0x12A526`. I'm basing this suggestion off the sample test rule [here](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara/blob/dafa3b54494a2aa81c3f284dca8e7ce9acf8d0c2/tests/test-pe.c).

Answer (score 0):

Been 5 years but I believe using the `at` syntax would work

```
strings:
  $ep_data = { 12 A5 26 }
condition:
  $ep_data at pe.entry_point
```